# Laravel ErrorException, Performing Multiple dynamic drop down

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I have four tables:
**`asset_category`** table(columns `'asset_category_id'`, `'category'`), an **`assets`** table(columns `'asset_id'`,`'asset_category_id'`,`'manufacturer_id'`, `'department_id'`),
**`manufacturers`** table (columns `manufacturers_id`, `manufacturer`) and **`departments`** table (columns `department_id`, `department`). The `asset` table columns are linked with the other three table. I'm performing a dynamic drop down in the form to insert into the `asset` table

**Asset.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{url('/insertAsset')}}" method="POST" edata-parsley-validate novalidate>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userName">Asset ID*</label>
        <input type="text" name="asset_id" parsley-trigger="change" required placeholder="Asset ID" class="form-control" id="userName" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userName">Asset Category ID*</label>
        <select name="asset_category_id" parsley-trigger="change" required placeholder="Asset Category ID" class="form-control">
       <option>Select an Asset Category</option>
        @foreach( $asset_categories as $asset_category )
            <option value=" {{$asset_category->asset_category_id}}"> {{ $asset_category->category }} </option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userName">Asset Manufacture ID*</label>
        <select name="manufacturer_id" parsley-trigger="change" required class="form-control">
            <option>Select a Manufacturer</option>
                @foreach( $manufacturers as $manufacturer )
                    <option value=" {{$manufacturer->manufacturer_id}}"> {{ $manufacturer->manufacturer }} </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userName">Department ID*</label>
        <select name="department_id" parsley-trigger="change" required placeholder="Department ID" class="form-control" >
            <option>Select a Department</option>
            @foreach( $departments as $department )
                <option value=" {{$department->department_id}}"> {{ $department->department }} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

<div class="form-group text-right m-b-0">
<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
    Submit
</button>
</div>
```

**AssetController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Asset;
use App\Asset_category;
use App\Manufacturer;
use App\Department; 

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AssetController extends Controller
{   
    public function asset_category(){
        $asset_categories = Asset_category::all();
    return view('asset', ['asset_categories' => $asset_categories]);
    }

    public function manufacturer(){
        $manufacturers = Manufacturer::all();
        return view('asset', ['manufacturers' => $manufacturers]);
    }

    public function department(){
        $departments = Department::all();
        return view('asset', ['departments' => $departments]);
    }    

}
```

**Web.php**

```
<?php    

Route::get('/asset', function (){
    return view('asset');
} );   

Route::get('/asset', 'AssetController@asset_category');
Route::get('/asset', 'AssetController@department');
Route::get('/asset', 'AssetController@manufacturer');    


/*POST */    
Route::post('/insertAsset', 'AssetController@add');
```

When run the application, i get an `ErrorException` which states:

```
Undefined variable: asset_categories (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_app\resources\views\asset.blade.php).
```

After thorough testing i find out that, just one drop down displays because the laravel routes only one variable from one function among the 3 functions in the `web.php` and the other two variable from the other functions are not sent to the `asset.blade.php`. So now i want a way to route the other variables to the asset.blade.php. Please help if you understand it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The first thing is that Laravel will only match the first route with the specific ID and specific type. In these case will only find the first route `GET /asset`.
- To do what I undestand you want. You need to create only one method, that will return the three variables to the view

  ```
  public function asset(){
      $asset_categories = Asset_category::all();
      $manufacturers = Manufacturer::all();
      $departments = Department::all();
      return view('asset', ['asset_categories' => $asset_categories, 
                       'manufacturers' => $manufacturers, 'departments' => $departments]);
  }
  ```

  And only one route
  `Route::get('/asset', 'AssetController@asset');`